# about contradiction in summing numbers arranged in square arrays

Tags: sequences-and-series

you know, when we sum numbers arranged in square arrays, you can first sum in rows, and then sum all of it. Or you can first sum in lines and then sum all of it. Obviously, these two ways leads to same answer. 
However, i found weird sequence that breaks this obvious rules..
1
1/2 -1/2
1/4  1/4 -1/4 -1/4

1/8  1/8  1/8  1/8  -1/8 -1/8 -1/8 -1/8

and so it goes on infinitely...

so, the sum of rows are 1,0,0,0,... so it is 1
and the sum of lines are 2,0,0,0,... so it is 2
and it means 1=2??
can anyone tell me why this thing happens?